# How to switch on LED by php interface with Raspberry | Arduino

Tags: arduino, php, apache-httpd

In my project I've connected a Raspberry Pi 2 and Arduino by serial USB. I would switch on some leds, by a php interface.

So, the PHP interface is ok, but when I chose the led to put on, nothing happens. The serial wired is ok because I can switch on the leds by using the IDE tool on the RPi 2.

The help PHP page is correctly reached.

After a lot of research, I think that the problem could be the permission settings. The php web interface, could use `/dev/ttyACM0` port, but maybe, it doesn't happens.

Considering the possible users like, www-data (Apache2), root and pi, after having seen some guides online, I'm confused.
I can't understand wich user has to be enable in orther to use /dev/ttyACM0 port.

In conclusion, I attach the command used:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0
sudo usermod -a -G dialout www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved ! ! ! It was not a permissions problem, but a problem with the php code. version of Debian that I used "Jessie" version seems to have some problems with php, so I replaced it with the "wheezy" version now everything works. But we must always activate "minicom", but just do it start on boot.